# AngularJS - Empty option in select with ajax source

Tags: angularjs, ajax, scope, html-select

I have a select element that should be filled with some options that I need to retrieve from an API call, then set the first one as selected.

But Angular creates an empty option at first position and I don't know how to delete it.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedPositionFamily">
    <option ng-repeat="pf in positionFamilies" ng-value="pf.uuid">{{pf.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
function Controller($scope, PositionFamilyService) {

    $scope.positionFamilies = [];

    $scope.selectedPositionFamily = "";

    initController();

    function initController() {

        PositionFamilyService.getAll({ 'sort' : 'order,asc' })
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.positionFamilies = data.content;
                $scope.selectedPositionFamily = $scope.positionFamilies[0].uuid;                        
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing can be achieved using ng-options

**html**

```
<select ng-model="selectedPositionFamily" 
ng-options="pf.uuid as pf.name for pf in positionFamilies"></select>
```

**js**

```
$scope.positionFamilies = [{uuid:1, name:"val1"},
{uuid:2, name:"val2"},{uuid:3, name:"val3"}];
$scope.selectedPositionFamily = $scope.positionFamilies[0].uuid;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mxno5esv/